# Append to text file in Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, append

I am getting error from my code. Basically, I have some function called Triangulate

```
tringulate = cv2.triangulatePoints(projection_matrix_1, projection_matrix_2, projection_points1, projection_points_2)
```

The function gives me some output like this

```
[[ X1 X2 X3 ... Xn]
 [ Y1 Y2 Y3 ... Yn]
 [ Z1 Z2 Z3 ... Zn]
 [ W1 W2 W3 ... Wn]]
```

I am also having another function for detecting the descriptors from some camera frame.

```
kps, desc = self.detector.detectAndCompute(self.image, None)
```

The output of the desc is like this

```
here [[ 97  93   2 ..., 255  63   1]
 [ 64 141   1 ..., 123 255  62]
 [ 97  29  14 ..., 253 127   3]
 ..., 
 [218 233 131 ..., 253 255  15]
 [  1 237 143 ..., 127 255  15]
 [ 97 253  13 ..., 176 255   3]]

here [[ 64 141   0 ..., 123 255  31]
 [ 97  29  78 ..., 253 127   1]
 [  0  13   0 ..., 123 255  30]
 ..., 
 [ 97 253  15 ..., 255 255   3]
 [ 64 141   1 ...,   2  16  48]
 [  1 237 143 ..., 255 102  15]]
```

The output of both functions is changing whenever new reading is coming. The readings are coming from robot movement. It is recorded in rosbag.

Now I want to write a txt file which will have.

> X1 Y1 Z1 W1 desc1 X2 Y2 Z2 W2 desc2  ... Xn Yn Zn Wn descn

In which x y z w are outputs from first reading of triangulate and desc1 is output from first reading of desc function .. etc till it finishes.

I was able to take the readings of triangulate and add it without any issues from this code

```
        f = open("11.txt", "w")  # Erases the file content.
        f.close()

here exists both functions

        f = open("11.txt", "a")
        f.write(','.join(str(v) for v in self.tringulate.T.flat) + '\n')
        f.close()
```

I was able to save X1 Y1 Z1 W1 X2 Y2 Z2 W2 but without the desc1 ... desc2 ...etc

Comment: Random tip: Consider to use `with` statement to automatically close files without need of a `close`. This won't adress your issue, but it can't harm to know those things.

Comment: @Saelyth Thanks a lot:) But any advice about what I am trying to achieve would be appreciated:)

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what is your problem. The question is confusing, or explained in a way that I don't understand what you want to do and where you are struck.

Comment: @Saelyth Basically, I would like to have txt file which have

X1 Y1 Z1 W1 Desc1 X2 Y2 Z2 W2 Desc2 .. up to Xn Yn Zn Wn Descn 

x y z and w I am getting as output from function Triangulate which is mentioned above. I am getting them in the shape of [[x1 x2 x3 x3 ..][y1 y2 y3 y4 ..][z1 z2 z3 z4 ..][w1 w2 w3 w4 ..]] . but Desc I am getting it from the function detectAndcompute mentioned above , the shape of it is mentioned above.... How can I append them to txt. My code above was capable to append x1 y1 z1 w1 x2 y2 z2 w2 ... xn yn zn wn but without Desc1 Desc2 ... Descn. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the two arrays(tringulate, desc) first and then store them in the file. [Refer to this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_append.htm)

You can use the numpy library for this. First, convert both the array in numpy array(if they are not numpy arrays) and then append them using np.append() function with axis=1.